# Await the loading of background Image in Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm sorry if this question sounds a bit weird.

I have an issue with how long it takes to load a backgroundImage in a controller. I am using a Container's backgroundImage property as a background for my Scaffold. But during the loading of that particular page, it shows a black background until the image is loaded.

Is there a way I can wait for the image to be loaded before I navigate to the said page?

Below is my Code sample of the page in question:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage(imgSubscriptionBGPNG),
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
    ),
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Column()
  ),
);
```

Comment: did you try precacheImage https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html

Comment: Thank you. Pre-Cacheing the image worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew! It wasn't that difficult to solve after all, thanks to @Mr Random for his noble suggestion.

I did precache the image on the previous screen and passed it as an argument to the next page. That worked for me.

Here are the code snippets:

In the State class of the first screen:

```
final bgImage = AssetImage(imgSubscriptionBGPNG);
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  precacheImage(bgImage, context);
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

And in the build function:

```
BtnButton(
 onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context,CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (context) 
               => SubscriptionScreen(bgImage: bgImage)));}),
```